# How to make a login page with two Azure Active Directories in the back?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

I want to make an authentication page which allows a user to pick between two azure active directories. They can then enter their usernames and passwords and authenticate. Then they can use the application if authorised.

How would I go about implementing the authentication page? I don't completely understand how to implement a connection between two different active directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your application **multi-tenant** by finding the "Multi-Tenanted"switch on the properties page of your application registration in the Azure portal and setting it to "Yes".

With a multi-tenant application, requests are sent to an endpoint that multiplexes across all Azure AD tenants: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common` .When Azure AD receives a request on the /common endpoint, it signs the user in and as a consequence discovers which tenant the user is from. You don't need to let user choose which directory he want to login .

Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview) for more about how to sign in any Azure Active Directory (AD) user using the multi-tenant application pattern . And [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect) is a code sample  shows how to build a multi-tenant .Net MVC web application that uses OpenID Connect to sign up and sign in users from any Azure Active Directory tenant .

In addition ,if you want to restrict certain tenants when using multi-tenant applications on Azure AD , you can perform validation in your own code in application by checking the tenantID (tid) claim in JWT token .

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to register the app to work with both active directories in Azure. @Nan can you help with that?

Comment: Make the application  multi-tenant  , then users in any Azure AD tenant will be able to sign in to your application after consenting to use their account with your application. Please refer to document and code sample  shown above