# How can you add two Azure Active Directories to a single tenant? (For a multi-tenant application)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Wanted to make an authentication page with two separate active directories in the back. Made a multi-tenant application, but need to be able to add two ADs into a single tenant group, so that the multi-tenant application can interact with both ADs. Is that even possible?

Comment: Can you please describe what you mean by `but need to be able to add two ADs into a single tenant`? Kindly edit your question and provide these details.

Comment: Sorry about that. Editted

Comment: The question still isn't clear. What is your actual requirement vs what are ideas you're exploring to achieve your requirement?

Comment: The simplest thing would be to have to Azure AD tenants, one for each on-premises AD. You'd then make your application multi-tenant and restrict it to [only allow two issuers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#update-your-code-to-handle-multiple-issuer-values), the two Azure ADs.

Comment: Alternatively you could have a single Azure AD and synchronize both on-premise ADs to that single Azure AD, though this is discouraged. Your application wouldn't need to be multi-tenant in that case.

Comment: Based on the [previews thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187707/how-to-make-a-login-page-with-two-azure-active-directories-in-the-back), you were developing a multi-tenant application for two Azure Active Directory. For this scenario, there is no need to merge two Azure Active Directory into one. And we are only need to enable the `Multi-Tenanted` feature for the app register on Azure portal. Did you still have problem about login two Azure Active Directory in the web app?

Comment: Yes, I made two ADs, which seems to make their own tenants automatically. Then I tried adding the application to one. Not too sure what to do from then on.

Comment: If you create the application in Azure AD "A" and mark the application as multi-tenant and use "common" in the auth URL's instead of the tenant identifier, you should be able to sign in as a user from the other "B" directory.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. Says that the user is not a part of AD "A".

Comment: Are you sure than you also modify **tenant** in the authority with `common`? You may share the details steps to help others identity this issue.